# Get all members from the mailing list using MailChimp API 3.0

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/members/lists-members-collection

Using this resource we can obtain only first 10 members. How to get all?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is quite simple - use **offset** and **count** parameters in URL query:

```
https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/b5b5fdc2fa/members?offset=150&count=10
```

Finally I found PHP API client for MailChimp API v3:
https://github.com/pacely/mailchimp-api-v3

And official docs about pagination.. I missed it before :(
http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/api-3-overview

Comment: @pocockn You can grab them in two steps: 1) [get total items](https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/29e5c010dc/members?fields=total_items)  2) [get all members](https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/29e5c010dc/members?count=TOTAL_FROM_PREV_RESPONSE). Let me know if you'll find a better solution :)

Comment: count seems to be maximized at 1000. So you need to iterate through all members in multiple calls.

Comment: It's worth mentioning there's restrictions on the count you can use in the request. For me it seems to top out around 700.

Comment: when trying to make a curl call to a "normal" list of about 2600 members I get Internal server error from the mailchimp api, I am trying at the moment to export the list members to an excel file and I am stuck, so the only solution I can see for large list it's to make incremental requests and save the results on a file or db, not a nice solution.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled on this one while researching a way to get all list members in MC API 3.0 as well.  I noticed that there were some comments on the API timing out when trying to get all list members on one page.  I also encountered this at first but was able to overcome it by limiting the fields in the result by using the 'fields' param.  My code is for a mass deleter so all I really needed was the ID of each member to put together a batch delete request.  Here's how my fetch request looks (psuedo-code):

```
$total_members = $result['total_items'];//get number of members in list via previous request
https://usXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/foobarx/members?fields=members.id&count=total_members
```

This way I'm able to fetch over 15,000 subscribers on one page without error.

Answer (score 5):

Using `offset` and `count` parameters are correct as mentioned in some of the other answers, but becomes tedious for large lists.

A more efficient way, is to use a client for the MailChimp API. I used [mailchimp3 for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mailchimp3/1.0). Using this, it's pretty easy to get all members on your list because it handles the pagination. Here's how you would do it.

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp

client = MailChimp('YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY')
client.lists.members.all('YOUR_LIST_ID', get_all=True, fields="members.email_address")
```

Answer (score 4):

offset and count is the official way on the docs, but the problem is that has linear slowdown. It appears to be an n^2 solution, so if you have 20,000 items, you're in trouble. Their docs http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members warn you against using offset.

If you're scenario permits you to use other filters (like since_last_changed), then you can do it quickly.  See [What is the right syntax for "timeframe" in MailChimp API 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875377/mailchimp-api-3-0-what-is-the-right-syntax-for-timeframe) for format for datetime.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it just with count, making an API call to the [list root](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#read-get_lists_list_id) so in the next API call you include the count parameter and you have all your list members.

I ran into issues with this because I had a moderate list with 2600 members and MailChimp was throwing an error, but it worked with 1500 people.

So for a list bigger than 1500 members I use [MailChimp export API](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/) bare in mind that this is going to get discontinued but I could not find any other acceptable solutions.

Alternatively for bigger lists (>1500) you could get the total of members and then make multiple api calls to the [Member endpoint](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/) but I really dislike that :(

If anyone has a better alternative I would be really glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

With MailChimp.Net.

Use the offset value.

```
List<Member> listMembers = new List<Member>();
IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager(MailChimpApiKey);
bool moreAvailable = true;
int offset = 0;
while (moreAvailable)
{
    var listMembers = manager.Members.GetAllAsync(yourListId, new MemberRequest
    {
        Status = Status.Subscribed,
        Limit = 250,
        Offset = offset
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var Allmembers = listMembers.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    foreach(Member member in Allmembers)
    {
        listMembers.Add(member);
    }
    if (Allmembers.Count() == 250)
        //if the count is < of 250 then it means that there aren't more results
        offset += 250;
    else
        moreAvailable = false;
}
```